# SwiftUI: Hide keyboard but show cursor

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I want to use custom buttons to input text into a `TextField`, but still show and move the cursor. Is there a way to hide the default keyboard while still showing the cursor?

I was hoping for something like this:

```
TextField("", text: $text)
    .keyboardType(.none)
```

Here is what it currently looks like.

[image: Here is what it currently looks like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIViewRepresentable` class and pass the input view as an empty view.

```
struct HideKeyboardTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<HideKeyboardTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        textField.inputView = UIView()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<HideKeyboardTextField>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> HideKeyboardTextField.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: HideKeyboardTextField

        init(parent: HideKeyboardTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        HideKeyboardTextField(placeholder: "Input", text: $text)
    }
}
```