# How to keep focus and hide keyboard at the same time - SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a text editor and it uses a custom panel for the formatting options. Is there a way to keep the input focused and close the keyboard?

Comment: Does this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68266905/14733292

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. What do you mean by formatting options? What have you tried? What part of your code doesn't work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This may help..check
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-for-a-textfield